# keybinding which will respect minor mode override

Tags: key-bindings, evil

I am trying evil mode and want to keep emacs's `C-k` when in `insert` mode.

`C-k` is `kill-line`

but when smartparens-mode is on, it's
`sp-kill-hybrid-sexp`

So I can't just bind `C-k` to `kill-line` in `evil-insert-state-map`, can I?
(Would smartparens pick up and rebind automatically?)

-- edit

For future reference,

Minor mode key binding > Major mode > Global mode

So more specific mode bindings are used.

In order to override minor mode binding for a major mode,
you need to create a new map that has the new binding and insert into the `minor-mode-overriding-map-alist`

Darn..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minor mode keymaps already override the global key map. But I see that `evil-insert-state-map` is a minor mode map, in which case it can override the other minor modes if it is earlier in the mode list. (See [chapter 23.8 Searching the Active Keymaps](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Searching-Keymaps.html) for a concise description of exactly which keymaps are searched and in what order.) You can use `C-h b` to get a list of active key maps, and the order they are searched in, for the current buffer.

You could bind `C-k` to a new command that checks to see if smartparens is enabled, and only calls `kill-line` if it is not. That won’t scale, but for one command it is simple enough.

A quick check of the evil-mode documentation (`C-h i` is your friend), shows that if you want to do it right then you should add a hook to `evil-insert-state-entry-hook` which will check for smartparens mode and enable an additional minor mode containing your keybindings. That way you could bind `C-k` to `kill-line` in `evil-insert-state-keymap`, and then bind it to `sp-kill-hybrid-sexp` in your new minor mode’s keymap. The new minor mode will be first in the minor mode list, ensuring that it shadows the bindings in the `evil-insert-state-keymap`. Naturally you would want to remove that minor mode in a hook added to `evil-insert-state-exit-hook`.

Comment: Thank you. 

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Local-Keymaps.html it might not be accurate but much more accessible.  

I'm after rebinding it in python-mode not in entire evil-insert-state-keymap.  

I was able to do it though. by using minor-mode-overriding-map-alist